# Grouping in mongoose aggregation according to condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I am building a chat app based on the MERN stack and need to fetch all chats for a specific user.

This is my chat messages schema:

```
const message = mongoose.Schema({
  from: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
    required: true,
  },
  to: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
    required: true,
  },
  text: { type: String, required: false },
  imgLink: { type: String, required: false },
  sentAt: { type: Date, required: true },
  deliveredAt: { type: Date, required: false },
  readAt: { type: Date, required: false },
});
```

Is there a way to fetch all chats for a user and group them by who sent/recieved these chats.

I used this aggregation pipeline

```
const fetchChatPipeline = (_id) => {
  return [
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            to: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id),
          },
          {
            from: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id),
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        sentAt: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$from",
        from: { $first: "$from" },
        to: { $first: "$to" },
        messages: {
          $push: {
            text: "$text",
            imgLink: "$imgLink",
            sentAt: "$sentAt",
            deliveredAt: "$deliveredAt",
            readAt: "$readAt",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "from",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "from",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$from",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "to",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "to",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$to",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        to: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,
        },
        from: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,
        },
        messages: 1,
      },
    },
  ];
};
```

and got the following result:

```
{
    "chats": [
        {
            "_id": "60368ee8a4e8494c74ccbeec",
            "from": {
                "_id": "60368ee8a4e8494c74ccbeec",
                "name": "Jaivardhan Singh"
            },
            "to": {
                "_id": "603a637ab356a309dcca9099",
                "name": "Jai Singh "
            },
            "messages": [
                {
                    "text": "hello",
                    "sentAt": "2021-02-27T16:33:40.335Z"
                },
                {
                    "text": "What you upto",
                    "sentAt": "2021-02-27T16:34:16.852Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "603a637ab356a309dcca9099",
            "from": {
                "_id": "603a637ab356a309dcca9099",
                "name": "Jai Singh "
            },
            "to": {
                "_id": "60368ee8a4e8494c74ccbeec",
                "name": "Jaivardhan Singh"
            },
            "messages": [
                {
                    "text": "Hi",
                    "sentAt": "2021-02-27T16:35:32.343Z"
                },
                {
                    "text": "Nothing just chilling",
                    "sentAt": "2021-02-27T16:35:41.720Z"
                },
                {
                    "text": "What you upto",
                    "sentAt": "2021-02-27T16:35:49.662Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way i can merge these two chats in the results as they have common participants. Thanks.

Comment: Just `$group` by `null` since u have already filtered users in `$match` stage: Something like this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#examples

Comment: but doing that will merge all the messages together even if the participants in the chat are not same. In the above example there is chat in between 2 people only but if we add in a third person his chats will merge too

Comment: But `$match` stage will filter all third persons. `$match` will include only the sender(from) and receiver(to) right?

Comment: as you can see there is an $or in the match filter so it returns all the chat which are either sent by the _id or received by _id. So if the user with _id chats with a third person his results will also be included in the grouping

Comment: Ok. Check the updated answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `$match` stage as below and `$group` it by `null`

```js
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            { to: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) },
            { from: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) }
        ],
        to: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) }
    }
}
```